# How to get the newVal using Angularjs Watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular watch trigger a callback function when the value in a array changes. The function then must fetch the value in the array that has changed. Below is the code and the link to the fiddle

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Please modify the values, how to watch them?</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="col in columns">
          <input type="text" ng-model="col.field" />
          <input type="text" ng-model="col.displayName" />
      </li>
      </ul>

  </div>
</div>


    --------------------------------
 function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.columns = [
      { field:'title', displayName: 'TITLE'},
      { field: 'content', displayName: 'CONTENT' }
  ];
    $scope.$watch('columns', function(newVal) {
        alert(newVal);
    },true);
}
```

Link to the fiddle:-
http://jsfiddle.net/SYx9b/#&togetherjs=MLzovnvQAI

Answer (score 2):

Use function(newVal,oldVal){} , the first param will return you the new value and 2nd param will give you the old value.

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.columns = [
      { field:'title', displayName: 'TITLE'},
      { field: 'content', displayName: 'CONTENT' }
  ];
    $scope.$watch('columns', function(newVal,oldVal) {
        alert("OLD Data: "+JSON.stringify(oldVal));
        alert("NEW DATA: "+JSON.stringify(newVal));
    },true);
}
```

See working fiddle example.
http://jsfiddle.net/imhassan66/7dzyL/